# UIScrollView scrolls to different position while animating presentation of modal view controller

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, paging, presentmodalviewcontroller, scroll-paging

I'm using a `UIScrollView` for paging three different `UIViewControllers`. The pager initializes to display page 1 from start. So the user can swipe left or right from the beginning. When I present a modal view controller from the mid view controller, the `UIScrollView` temporarily scrolls to the first page during the animation of the presented view controller. When I dismiss the modal view controller everything's back to normal and the `UIScrollView` displays the center view controller.

I would expect (and want) the `UIScrollView` to keep it's position during the animation.

This is not a technical bug that causes a crash or something, it's just ugly.

Anyone ever had that before? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: so to be clear, the problem is that your scroll view is scrolling back to your first page when presenting a modal transition from the 2nd page? also, are you using parent-child view controller containment?

Comment: can you please try to disable paging on the uiscrollview and check if it still occurs?

Comment: Did you try setting the property scrollEnabled to NO & then back to YES ?

Comment: Yes, correct. And yes, we're using view controller containment.

Comment: Setting `scrollEnabled` to no right before loading the modal view does not help. Same for `setPagingEnabled`. It's just weird because when dismissing the modal view controller during the animation I can see the wanted second view. Not the first one that it's animating to during the show animation.

Comment: That certainly is weird, I'm using pretty much the exact same architecture in my app and i'm not seeing this issue, can you show your source code?

Comment: We fixed it. This behavior was caused by an overwritten `viewWillDisappear` in our super class. For some reason (don't know why yet) someone reset the frame manually in there.

Comment: Glad to see you fixed the issue!

Comment: Your fix was remove the `[super viewWillDisappear:animated];` line from your `viewWillDisappear` method?, because not work for me

Answer (score 0):

**I've had this same problem, and after much investigation it appears to be a bug in UIKit relating to scrollviews and AutoLayout. Here's the 'fix'...**

**In viewDidDisappear:, save the current scrollview contentOffset to a property, and reset it to zero:**

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    self.previousContentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;

    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
}
```

**Then, in viewWillAppear:, reset the content offset back to what it was previously. I had to dispatch this onto the main queue to get it to work correctly:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(self.previousContentOffset, CGPointZero))
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.scrollView.contentOffset = self.previousContentOffset;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: in `viewDidDisappear` and in `viewWillDisappear` too, the `scrollview.contentOffset` is `{0, 0}`. And `self.scrollView.contentOffset = manual offset;` is not execute, only works if add delay.